# groupBy on case class field dynamically in scala

Tags: scala, dynamic, grouping, case-class

How can I perform groupBy operation on a List of case class having case classes as fields? 
For example:

```
case class F1(str1:Option[String],str2:Option[String])
case class F2(int1:Option[Int],int2:Option[Int])

case class Parent(str:F1, int:F2)
```

Let's say I have a List of case class Parent and I have to perform groupBy on any of the sub case classes field dynamically.

```
val data = List(Parent(F1(Some("abc"), Some("pqr"))), F2(Some(20), Some(30)))
                Parent(F1(Some("abc"), Some("xyz"))), F2(Some(20), Some(30)))
                Parent(F1(Some("def"), Some("pqr"))), F2(None, Some(30)))
                Parent(F1(Some("def"), Some("pqr"))), F2(Some(20), Some(30)))
                Parent(F1(None, Some("xyz"))), F2(None, Some(30))))
```

I want to perform `data.groupBy("str1")` where "str1" is the field name of case calss F1 and will be passed dynamically.

If this operation successfully executes then output will be:

```
Map(Some("abc") -> List(Parent(F1(Some("abc"), Some("pqr"))), F2(Some(20), Some(30))),
                        Parent(F1(Some("abc"), Some("xyz"))), F2(Some(20), Some(30)))),
    Some("def") -> List(Parent(F1(Some("def"), Some("pqr"))), F2(None, Some(30))),
                        Parent(F1(Some("def"), Some("pqr"))), F2(Some(20), Some(30)))),
    None        -> List(Parent(F1(None, Some("xyz"))), F2(None, Some(30)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

for a `List[+A]`, groupBy has signature

```
def groupBy[K](f: (A) ⇒ K): Map[K, List[A]]
```

For you, `A` is a `Parent`, so you could use

```
data.groupBy(_.str.str1)
```

Here `.str` maps to the `F1`, then `.str1` maps to the `Option[String]` you want to group by.

In particular, we pass an `A => K` to groupBy, rather than a value. If you had tried to pass (something like) a string instead e.g. `(_ => "str1")` to groupBy, it would map everything to that string while grouping, so everything would end up in the same group, and you'd just have `Map("str1" -> data)`.

As for passing dynamically `"str1"`, you could pass `_.str.str1`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I would like to further elaborate on the situation.  groupBy can be performed on any field(str1, str2, int1 or int2) and that field is not known at compile time, the code will only have that information at runtime. I can think of one way of doing that by using pattern matching, for example: case "str1" => data.groupBy( _.str.str1);    case "str2" => data.groupBy( _.str.str2); .  Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: reflection should be able to do this, but never used it myself https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html

Comment: that said, if there are only four cases, I'd go with sth like pattern matching